# Symfony2 ->set doesn't update the database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I need to create a web application for a touristic agency which promotes auctions online of travels. I've been asked to create a code which allows a user to bid one time before the auction starts, in fact the auction can be seen online while it is not started yet and can receive only one bid from every bidder before it starts. When the auction starts the bidders are allowed to bid only one other time. I know, it's pretty odd. However, with my code I can insert the first bid smoothly but when it comes to update the bid with a new and last price it simply doesn't update the data. I don't know why because it perfectly retrieves the object of the bid and the doctrine's names of each field are right. The fields' names are the following: 
- setAmount (how much you bid which changes every time you bid), 
- setFirstbid (which turns to 1 one you bid the first time), 
- setLastBid (which turns to 1 when you bid the second and last time).

It simply won't update these three fields.

This is the code:

```
  public function createAction(Request $request, ProductInfo $productInfo)
    {
```

** I first get the user info **

```
$user_fos = $this->get("security.context")->getToken()->getUser();
    $id_user = $user_fos->getId();
    $id_product = $productInfo->getId();

        $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("CasaUserBundle:User")->find($id_user);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
```

** I set the bid **

```
$entity = new BidsInfo();
```

** I get info about the auction I want to bid for **
        $

```
entity_prod =$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("ReverseAuctionReverseAuctionBundle:ProductInfo")->find($productInfo);
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity, $productInfo);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $dati = $form->getData();


        ** With the following function I verify how many times the bidder has bid and then if he is allowed to bid **


$how_many_bids = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("ReverseAuctionReverseAuctionBundle:BidsInfo")->CheckPermit($id_product, $id_user, $dati->getBAmount());
```

** I check the form validation and if I'm allowed to bid **

```
    if ($form->isValid() && $how_many_bids[0]!=0) {
            try{

                 $em->beginTransaction();

          ** this is the first  bid which works pretty well **
            if($how_many_bids[0] == 1){


$entity->setUserInfo($user);
```

** How much he bids **

```
$entity->setBAmount($dati->bAmount);

        $entity->setProductInfo($productInfo);

        $entity->setBidfirst(1);
        $entity->setBidfinal(0);
        $em->persist($entity);
```

** the following is the second bid which doesn't work with the updating process **

```
    }else if($how_many_bids[0] == 2){
```

** I get the bidder's object **

```
$bid_getid = $em->getRepository("ReverseAuctionReverseAuctionBundle:BidsInfo")->findOneBy(array('UserInfo' => $id_user, 'ProductInfo' => $id_product));
```

** It doesn't store the following data **

```
 $biduser->setBAmount($dati->bAmount);
            $biduser->setBidfirst(1);

        $biduser->setBidfinal(1);
        $em->flush();
        $em->commit();


        }else{
            throw new Exception("No data found!");
        }


        $em->flush();
        $em->commit();
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $em->rollback();
        throw $ex;
        }
```

Do you have any clue why it  doesn't store data when I update the bid? It seems setBAmount, setBidFinal and setBidFirst don't work when I update them.

Comment: Are you sure the code is evaluated? If you cannot update, then `$how_many_bids` never quals 2, ar I'm wrong?

Comment: the $how_many_bids value turns to 2, I know that because I used var_dump("something") after " if($how_many_bids[0] == 2){  " and it shows what's inside var_dump, so, it passes the evaluation.